# Echo acoustic when Android recording with background music playing

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am developing a App on Android. The base function is recording with background music playing.

1. use ffmpeg to decode a mp3 file to PCM data(BG PCM), and play these data by AudioTrack(to Speaker).
2. use AudioRecord to record voice to PCM(captured PCM).
3. I mix BG PCM and voice PCM(BG PCM/2 + captured PCM/2), and save to a recording.pcm file
4. I play the recording.pcm, but including echo acoustic
5. I know the background sound is captured by the MIC together with voice.
6. Mybe the echo acoustic is lead by GB PCM and voice PCM is not synchonous!

how to resolve it ?